# What constitutes side chain atoms in pdb file?

Tags: bioinformatics

I previously calculated phi, psi, and omega, pretty easily from .pdb file. Because their definitions are rather straight-forward. For instance, I know that they require four cartesian coordinates (four atoms) that are set

```
phi: C-N-CA-C
psi: N-CA-C-N
omega: CA-C-N-CA
```

Now I am trying to calculate side-chain angles. I know this is similar to phi, psi, and omega (in that I will need 4 atoms per angle). However, I am having difficulty reading the .pdb file and determining what atoms in the first place constitute the side chains? For instance, in the following segment (I removed hydrogens and the one carbon per residue without a subscript):

```
1 N -14.152 0.961 4.712
1 CA -13.296 0.028 3.924
1 O -11.358 1.432 3.941
1 CB -13.571 0.173 2.426
1 CG -15.046 -0.135 2.144
1 SD -16.174 1.270 1.982
1 CE -17.702 0.313 1.823
2 N -11.121 -0.642 4.703
2 CA -9.669 -0.447 4.998
2 O -9.036 -2.736 4.724
2 CB -9.462 -0.447 6.516
2 OG1 -10.399 0.505 7.010
2 CG2 -8.090 0.103 6.896
3 N -7.990 -1.247 3.462
3 CA -7.173 -2.314 2.811
3 O -5.487 -1.663 4.367
3 CB -6.881 -1.930 1.359
3 CG -8.162 -1.388 0.715
3 CD1 -8.594 -0.102 0.975
3 CD2 -8.903 -2.180 -0.135
3 CE1 -9.749 0.380 0.392
3 CE2 -10.057 -1.699 -0.718
3 CZ -10.490 -0.415 -0.457
3 OH -11.645 0.066 -1.038
4 N -5.204 -3.598 3.323
4 CA -3.922 -3.881 4.044
4 O -2.647 -4.537 2.142
4 CB -4.003 -5.297 4.612
4 CG -3.169 -5.399 5.890
4 CD -2.632 -6.837 6.002
4 CE -2.044 -7.084 7.401
4 NZ -2.526 -8.390 7.935
```

Would the first few angles be between atoms as such:

```
N-CA-O-CB
CA-O-CB-CG
O-CB-CG-SD
CB-CG-SD-CE
```

In other words, would I be including atoms like O, SD, etc? Or do I only include subscripts in the order A, B, G, D, E, Z (anything else)? So that my first few angles would be:

```
N-CA-CB-CG
CA-CB-CG-CE
CG-CE-N-CA
CE-N-CA-CB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you usually just include the numbered carbons (so the second option that you showed would be correct). The exception is when there aren't enough carbons to define an angle. For instance, in cysteine you use the sulpher instead of a gamma carbon. You can find a list of the standard side chain angles for each amino acid [here](http://www.ccp14.ac.uk/ccp/web-mirrors/garlic/garlic/commands/dihedrals.html).

For more information, see [this page](http://kinemage.biochem.duke.edu/teaching/anatax/html/anatax.1b.html).